# MultiValueDictError Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want to store registration data in the database. When i hit the submit button i get the following error on the debug page:

[image]

All migrations are applied.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class register(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Email= models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone= models.IntegerField(max_length=13)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**Traceback**

```py
Internal Server Error: /register
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\good\test\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "J:\good\test\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "J:\good\test\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 108, in process_response
    return self.response_redirect_class(self.get_full_path_with_slash(request))
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "J:\good\test\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py", line 87, in get_full_path_with_slash
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/register/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
[29/Sep/2023 20:35:21] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 70661
```

The view I am trying to reach is the function register

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,"index.html")
def contact(request):
    return render(request,"contact.html")

def ideagained(request):
    return render(request,"idea_gained.html")

def idea(request):
    return render(request,"idea.html")

def ouridea(request):
    return render(request,"our_idea.html")

def aboutpage(request):
    return render(request,"aboutpage.html")

def register(request):
        your_name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        phone_number=request.POST['phone_number']
        account=request.POST['account']
        message=request.POST['message']
         

        user=user.objects.create_user(name=name)
        print("we wil call back you")
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

The key `name` doesn't exist.

```py
from .models import User

def register(request):
    your_name=request.POST['name']
    email=request.POST['email']
    phone_number=request.POST['phone_number']
    account=request.POST['account']
    message=request.POST['message']
    user=User.objects.create(your_name=your_name, email=email, phone_number=phone_number, account=account, message=message)
    print("we wil call back you")
    return redirect('/')
```

Please note that we tend to name models in CamelCase and the fields in lowercase. Also usually a model is, well, a noun. Your model thus should be:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email= models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone= models.IntegerField(max_length=13)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Comment: To add on to this; you cannot POST to a view without the URL ending in your browser (or `urls.py`) file ending as a slash. `/index` will always be invalid, while `/index/` is valid.

Comment: the append_slash  is not valid it show error like" You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/register/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings."@nigel239